# Variable changes during the execution. C++

Tags: c++, gdb, openmp

The program crashes with a segmentation fault, so I ran it with gdb. I found out that a member of a class is overridden during the runtime. Few facts:

- the class is not used in the function where it is overridden.
- the piece of the code where it is overridden is in omp critical section.

I checked the line where the debugger stops - the variables that are accessed in this line have different memory address.

Piece of gdb code:

```
(gdb) p SrcVelField
$1 = (SNGM::FieldVector *) 0x555555a237a0
(gdb) p *SrcVelField
$2 = {MeshRef = 0x55555592e530, Values = {data_ = 0x555555a237f0}, NbVar = 3, 
  NbVal = 8820, VarName = {data_ = 0x55555592f000}, 
  FieldName = "VelocityField"}
(gdb) p (*SrcVelField).NbVar
$3 = 3
(gdb) p &(*SrcVelField).NbVar
$4 = (unsigned int *) 0x555555a237b0
(gdb) watch -l *0x555555a237b0
Hardware watchpoint 2: -location *0x555555a237b0
(gdb) cont
Thread 1 "SNGM" hit Hardware watchpoint 2: -location *0x555555a237b0

Old value = 3
New value = -118991381
SNGM::GlobalEval<SNGM::FilterGaussian, 3u, 1u>::PerformGlobalEval ()
at ../SNGM/Numerics/GlobalEval.cpp:288
288   for (unsigned ii =     0; ii < nx; ii++){
(gdb) p &ii
$5 = (unsigned int *) 0x7fffffffc93c
(gdb) p &nx
$6 = (const unsigned int *) 0x7fffffffc950
```

I will be glad for hints why the value of `(*SrcVelField).NbVar` is changing there.

**UPDATE**
Disassembling the code in this line gives next:
- problematic rax value

```
(gdb) info registers
rax            0x555555a237b0   93824997275568
rbx            0x61a8   25000
```

And instructions to reach it

```
280                                     delete[] point;
0x0000555555595bcc <+1113>:  cmpq   $0x0,-0x58(%rbp)
0x0000555555595bd1 <+1118>:  je     0x555555595adc 

<PerformGlobalEvalEv._omp_fn.0(void)+873>
0x0000555555595bd7 <+1124>:  mov    -0x58(%rbp),%rax
0x0000555555595bdb <+1128>:  mov    %rax,%rdi
0x0000555555595bde <+1131>:  callq  0x555555564758
0x0000555555595be3 <+1136>:  jmpq   0x555555595adc 
<PerformGlobalEvalEv._omp_fn.0(void)+873>

281                             } //End for all particles
282
283     #pragma omp critical
   0x0000555555595f5b <+2024>:  callq  0x555555564ae8
   0x0000555555595f78 <+2053>:  callq  0x555555564a40

284                             {
285
286                                     for (unsigned kk = 0; kk < nz; kk++){
   0x0000555555595f60 <+2029>:  movl   $0x0,-0x15c(%rbp)
   0x0000555555595f6a <+2039>:  mov    -0x15c(%rbp),%eax
   0x0000555555595f70 <+2045>:  cmp    -0x148(%rbp),%eax
   0x0000555555595f76 <+2051>:  jb     0x555555595fed 



<PerformGlobalEvalEv._omp_fn.0(void)+2170>
   0x0000555555596005 <+2194>:  addl   $0x1,-0x15c(%rbp)
   0x000055555559600c <+2201>:  jmpq   0x555555595f6a 
<PerformGlobalEvalEv._omp_fn.0(void)+2039>

287                                             for (unsigned jj = 0; jj < ny; jj++){
   0x0000555555595fed <+2170>:  movl   $0x0,-0x158(%rbp)
   0x0000555555595ff7 <+2180>:  mov    -0x158(%rbp),%eax
   0x0000555555595ffd <+2186>:  cmp    -0x144(%rbp),%eax
   0x0000555555596003 <+2192>:  jb     0x555555596011 
<PerformGlobalEvalEv._omp_fn.0(void)+2206>
   0x0000555555596029 <+2230>:  addl   $0x1,-0x158(%rbp)
   0x0000555555596030 <+2237>:  jmp    0x555555595ff7 
<PerformGlobalEvalEv._omp_fn.0(void)+2180>

288                                                     for (unsigned ii = 0; ii < nx; ii++){
   0x0000555555596011 <+2206>:  movl   $0x0,-0x154(%rbp)
   0x000055555559601b <+2216>:  mov    -0x154(%rbp),%eax
   0x0000555555596021 <+2222>:  cmp    -0x140(%rbp),%eax
   0x0000555555596027 <+2228>:  jb     0x555555596032 
<PerformGlobalEvalEv._omp_fn.0(void)+2239>
=> 0x0000555555596177 <+2564>:  addl   $0x1,-0x154(%rbp)
```

Comment: The most common reason is indexing out of range.

Comment: *" member of a class is overridden during the runtime"*. *Data break point* (Watchpoints for gdb) might help.

Comment: There is no [mcve]; provide one if you expect useful answers instead of shots in the dark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is common behaviour when running out of stack/heap size or when an array is indexed out of bounds. Check your stack and heap sizes and verify that you are not exceeding them. Then check all instances of arrays/lists and verify that they are protected against out-of-bounds errors.